# How do I crop a fits.gz file and then view the cropped image using Python?

Tags: python, image, crop, astropy, fits

I have a couple of fits.gz files containing a large image that I need to crop around a specific coordinate. I have the image coordinates of the point I need to center the crop around, and I want to create a 2048x2048 image around this point. I also need to be able to view the cropped image to ensure everything worked properly, preferably with a small circle or something around the central point.

I've tried using the info from the opened fits file with

hdu_list = fits.open(filename.fits.gz)

image_data = hdu_list[0].data

and then using Cutout2D, but I can not save the result as a FITS image, and also can not view the cutout to see if it worked.

It seems like there should be a very simple and quick way to do this, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide a link to a representative source of such an image and a suitable set of coordinates.

Comment: What do you mean in both cases when you write "I can not"? What's stopping you? Is there an error?

Comment: the data saved to image_data is not an image, so it can not be saved as a FITS file. And I just simply can't find any code that would allow me to view the image. Downloading it is straight forward enough, but I can not find code that allows me to view the FITS image I just downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the results of the cutout into a `fits.PrimaryHDU` object and write it out following the example here:

https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/nddata/utils.html#saving-a-2d-cutout-to-a-fits-file-with-an-updated-wcs

The resulting FITS image can be opened in any FITS viewer.

Answer (score 0):

The Cutout2D class can't be directly written to a FITS file or viewed.

- The `fits.writeto` can conveniently write out FITS files using `numpy.ndarray` as input
- The `Cutout2D.data` attribute is a `numpy.ndarray` with the cutout result and can be used as input to `fits.writeto`
- If you want to view directly `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` function can also be used to view the `Cutout2D.data` without writing it out as a FITS file

See astropy documentation for more info and examples. https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.nddata.Cutout2D.html

Below is an example using the Cutout2D result and writing it to a FITS file. This FITS file has the image data in the primary HDU just like the input.

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.nddata.utils import Cutout2D

# read in the FITS file with image data in the primary HDU
hdu_list = fits.open('filename.fits.gz')
image_data = hdu_list[0].data

# perform the cutout with cutout 2d
coords = (2500, 2600)
newsize = (2048, 2048)
cut = Cutout2D(image_data, position=coords, size=newsize)

# IMPORTANT: to write out as fits file cut.data must be used
fits.writeto('cutout.fits', cut.data)
```

If you want to view the Cutout2D without writing to file

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# show 2D image using matplotlib
plt.imshow(cut.data)
```